# Asus Tuf A15 Gaming laptop (FA506IH) wont enter BIOS Mode

Tags: laptop, gaming, asus

I don't know what wrong with my laptop but when I try to enter bios mode its just show black screen and stuck there. I need to do ctrl + alt + del to go back and restart my laptop.

Laptop is working fine but I can not able to enter bios mode.

Comment: Try the following: get running, restart (slows down fast start up) and see if you can enter BIOS that way

Comment: no, it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can someone help me to fix this issue